Approximating Big O time complexity from runtime data
I am trying to optimize and profile some code for a university course. In an attempt to get extra marks I created a profiling program which measures the execution time for my desired function and exports it to a CSV file. From this, I had the idea to try to work out the big O time complexity.
Then it became apparent that I don't actually know how to compare this data to time complexity. There are so many parameters it isn't as simple as "above or below the curve". This problem reminds me of fitting polynomials to data.

To be clear, I'm not asking what time complexity this plot shows, I'm wondering if there is an applicable method. Another thing I was wondering about: is it better to measure linear or logarithmic N?
Is there an established analytical method for finding time complexity? Is this approach even sensible?

You are usually better analyzing the actual code, not the result of running it. That said, you might want to try larger N if possible to more clearly see the difference between O(n) and O(n log n) growth. (You might make the y axis logarithmic instead of linear, if that's what you mean by "better to measure linear or logarithmic".

Given that the dots seem to be converging below the linear line if you were to go past N = 100000, this is probably linear growth. Try larger values of N (though if larger values of N aren't feasible, the difference between O(n) and O(n lg n) probably doesn't matter.

You should not estimate complexity from timings. This is not reliable. Timings can look linear for small value and be quadratic for large value due to some (hidden) factor in the complexity. If you still want to measure this empirically then you should do the measure in log scale. This works for all basic polynomial complexity.

Oh and generally, in practice, we do not care much between O(n) and O(n log n) since the hidden constant is far more important than the log n factor. Not to mention n is nearly always <1e12 (since neither RAM nor stage devices are infinite) so log n behave like a parameter <30 ;) .

Your data looks extremely close to O(N). In fact it would be interesting to fit the regression line to it and look at R^2. I expect a perfect fit once you allow a constant. NB O(N) means it can be t = a + bN or t = c + dNlog(N) etc. Sometimes algorithms that are asymptotically much faster for large N but have setup overheads that make them inefficient for small trivial amounts of data. I'm with Jerome that you should increase test vector length N by factors of 2 each time and then do a log plot to get a feel for how an algorithm behaves. Gradient of line is the dominant power of N.
